# Google Mobile Ads in Win Phone 7 Applications

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, adsense

I'm interested in using Google Ads in my Win Phone 7 Application.  I've created a custom control that currently uses AdMob services to load ads, and I'm interested in incorporating a Google Ads provider (as well as any others I can). You can see the source for this control here: https://bitbucket.org/jacob4u2/moads/wiki/Home.

The best case scenario for me would be information about some kind of REST based JSON service that I could call and get back information like; Image Url, Ad Text, Ad Link Url.  I've already done some research with the javascript that is added to a website that calls out to such a service to get ads, I would just like to know the legality and possibility of using this underlying service for myself.

Here's a look at the underlying service request and response from the Google Mobile Website Ad Sense Javascript from Fiddler:

```
GET http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?oe=utf8&ad_type=text_image&client=[someclientstring]&color_bg=FFFFFF&color_border=336699&color_link=0000FF&color_text=000000&color_url=008000&correlator=1283032525791&dt=1283032525791&ea=0&flash=0&format=320x50_mb&frm=1&js=afmc-v1.1&output=html&u_ah=738&u_aw=1366&u_cd=32&u_h=768&u_w=1366&u_his=1&u_tz=-240&url=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A53339%2F&dtd=5 HTTP/1.1
Host: googleads.g.doubleclick.net
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.127 Safari/533.4
Referer: http://localhost:53339/
Accept: application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: __gads=ID=2ca5d68be0ad9c24:T=1276802611:S=ALNI_Mb20Pe5DhybgSn6XMox3s10fBFcgw; VWCUK200=L070410/Q46888_8658_5_070410_2_123110_188666x187920x070410x1x2/Q46885_8658_5_062810_1_123110_188672x187926x062910x1x1; id=ca99132260000f4|1782317/496326/14815|t=1272328868|et=730|cs=w4txjauw

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
P3P: policyref="http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/gcn_p3p_.xml", CP="CURa ADMa DEVa TAIo PSAo PSDo OUR IND UNI PUR INT DEM STA PRE COM NAV OTC NOI DSP COR"
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sat, 28 Aug 2010 21:54:25 GMT
Server: cafe
Cache-Control: private, x-gzip-ok=""
Content-Length: 603
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block

<html><body style="background-color:transparent"></body></html>
```

Looks like a lot of parameters, hopefully I've removed any confidential stuff.  Anyone ever looked into anything like this?

Comment: Hi Jacob, This sounds interesting. We have a thread going with WP7 Advertising Resources for 3rd Party Developers being documented. Your findings would be welcome. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsphone7series/thread/13e3ed9a-b966-42cf-9150-aba6156902cc

Answer (score 0):

I would contact Google to see if this is within their terms of service - it would be a shame to do the coding and then find out that that you get no revenue from them.

I would also consider how the ads are chosen if this is not a web page.  Typically the ads are chosen base don the page context.  In Silverlight apps on the phone there is no web page context.